# Where can I find a list of all the cutscenes in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Where can I find a list of all the cutscenes in World of Warcraft?

I am about to starting BC and I don't want to miss any of the lore cutscenes.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think vanilla and TBC had many cutscenes. [This page](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/media/videos/?page=4) might be a good place to start looking though.

Comment: What's your definition of a cutscene? In addition to a handful of FMV cutscenes, there are lots of in-engine cutscenes, and tons and tons of in-engine scripted events (where you still have full player control while events with dialog happen around you). The last case is by far the most common (most major quest chains have at least one of these, oftentimes several), so those are probably far too numerous to list.

Comment: Any FMV or in-engine cutscenes which are important to the lore

Comment: This doesn't really answer it so I will put in the comments. You can learn a lot of the World of Warcraft lore from this youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQ__nRnO2mE), as it goes in depth about the history and stories that have been involved.

Comment: ingame cutscenese only appeared in wow during wotlk.

Comment: I recommend checking out youtube channels, or searching the subreddit reddit.com/r/gamesthemovie.

Answer (score 1):

On the World Of Warcraft log in screen you should see a button called cinematic's in the bottom right corner. Click on it and you will see a list of cinematic trailers you can watch. Any other tbc cinematic's will be in the game.

Comment: The only cutscenes in vanilla and BC were the ones shown at character creation time. Cutscenes began to be added during Wrath, and those you see in level 1-60 questing now were added in Cataclysm.

Answer (score 0):

http://wow.gamepedia.com/Videos

Here :) Enjoy

Awesome videos!